# Getting BLOB data from XHR request in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, xmlhttprequest, blob

Can any one tel that how to GET Blob XHR request and XMLHttpRequest in ionic 2 , i have to fetch image url from the api .

This is my Ajax Code, i want in ionic 2

```
xhr.open('GET', "https://getbytitle('LE_COE_Mapping')/items(2)/AttachmentFiles('3.jpg')/$value");
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   // xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token token="' + token + '"');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token); 
xhr.onload = function (e) {

        var img = new Image();
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        img.src = url.createObjectURL(this.response);
        document.getElementById('Doctitle').appendChild(img);
       // alert(url.createObjectURL(this.response));
    };

    xhr.send();
```

Please i am stuck in this from the last two days.

Please Help me.
Thanks

Comment: You can get this by converting to base64 string . Have a look on this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/display-blob-image-from-server/112857/3

Comment: @amku91 please see my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i solved this below:
this.array: this is the url which we pass to get the blob url of the particular url:

```
const headers1 = new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.accessToken,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
              })
               const response = await this.http.get(this.array + "/$value", { headers: headers1, responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();

              let b: any = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
              var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
              console.log("this is url BLOB   " + url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got stuck in same problem once then this what I did :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        //this.response is your final response
        console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
        var img =  // your img syntax
        //your any custom code goes here
    }else{
  //show error message if you want to show
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://Your image url');// image url be like http://ab.cd/img.png
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   //send authorisation if you sending token 
xhr.send();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'handler'. in the line   handler(this.response)

Comment: @user9483522 handler is my custom function. OOPS sorry. remove this line and check what console say.

Comment: Can you tell me how to show image, i got the response then what to do @amku91

Comment: You can do like this : var blob = this.response;
document.getElementById("your image div id").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); @user9483522

Comment: Also append <div id="your image id"></div> into document where you want to show image. @user9483522

Comment: i am getting url with blob, but when i am taking that variable to html file using img src, it does not take the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178610/discussion-between-amku91-and-user9483522).